# how can i print the number of zeroes in an array in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countZeros(int[], int);


int main(void){
    int i,n; //simulate i=10
    cout<<"Please input number of elements: ";
    cin>>i; //i=10
    int arrayOfIntegers[i]; //arrayOfIntegers[10]
    cout<<"Please input "<<i<<" elements: ";
    cin>>arrayOfIntegers[i];

    cout << "The numbers of zeros in the array are: ";
    cout << countZeros(arrayOfIntegers, i);
    cout << endl;

}


int countZeros(int n[], int number)
{
    if (number > 1){
        if (n[number - 1] == 0){
            return 1 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
        }
        else{
            return 0 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
        }
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

my question is: how can i properly print the number of zeros in my array (the elements in my array will be coming from the user) because every time i try to run it, the program prints out 0 even if i have entered 3 zeroes in my array. i have to use recursion also for this problem.

Comment: There's already a function for this: `std::count`. Also, array bounds must be known at compile time.

Comment: You need to have a loop to get the input for array elements. Currently you are getting only one array value.

Comment: @dvasanth he's using recursion

Comment: Your issue is in `main()`. I ran your `countZeros()` code just fine. Make sure that you're initializing your values in your array correctly. Also, I found one bug in your `countZeros()` code: `if (number > 1)` should be `if (number >= 1)`, or your first element is never inspected.

Comment: `cin>>arrayOfIntegers[i];` doesn't fill the array with each digit the user types. What it does is fill a single element with the entire number that the user entered. Furthermore, an array defined with a size of i will have indexes 0 to i-1. So writing to index i is actually writing off the end of the array.

Comment: This question is not worthy of to be posted in SO. You should learn minimum about C++ from a well written book before you want to make ur hands dirty

Comment: i want to learn c++ by myself. i've watched videos and such things. its just that i dont get to have the privelage to ask a legit programmer about certain questions. that's why im asking help from programmers and beginners as well. hope you understand

Answer (score 2):

Two issues : 1) Your recursion has an incorrect stopping condition 2) Your `main` function isn't taking in all inputs.

```
int main(void){
    int i,n; //simulate i=10
    cout<<"Please input number of elements: ";
    cin>>i; //i=10
    int arrayOfIntegers[i]; //arrayOfIntegers[10]
    cout<<"Please input "<<i<<" elements: ";

    for(int j=0;j<i;j++) cin>>arrayOfIntegers[j];

    cout << "The numbers of zeros in the array are: ";
    cout << countZeros(arrayOfIntegers, i);
    cout << endl;

}


int countZeros(int n[], int number)
{
    if (number >= 1){
        if (n[number - 1] == 0){
            return 1 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
        }
        else{
            return 0 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
        }
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop inside `main` to take input:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countZeros(int[], int);


int main(void) {
    int i,n; //simulate i=10
    cout<<"Please input number of elements: ";
    cin>>i; //i=10
    int arrayOfIntegers[i]; //arrayOfIntegers[10]
    cout<<"Please input "<<i<<" elements: ";
    // here is the loop. I take input from array index 1
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        cin>>arrayOfIntegers[j];

    cout << "The numbers of zeros in the array are: ";
    cout << countZeros(arrayOfIntegers, i);
    cout << endl;

}


int countZeros(int n[], int number) {
    if(number == 0) return 0;
    if(n[number] == 0) return 1 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
    else return 0 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
}
```

Comment: i've also read in a pdf about c++ that we can also use the recursion process in order to read an array. but im having a hard time in trying to figure out a process where in i dont get to use any loops to read the elements in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You must read the array in a loop, see the code below. The stopping condition is `n>0` not `n>1`. Everything else works in your code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countZeros(int[], int);


int main(void){
    int i,n; //simulate i=10
    cout<<"Please input number of elements: ";
    cin>>i; //i=10
    int arrayOfIntegers[i]; //arrayOfIntegers[10]
    cout<<"Please input "<<i<<" elements: "<<endl;
    for(int k=0;k<i;k++) // HERE YOU NEED A LOOP
    {
        cout<<"arrayOfIntegers["<<k<<"]="; 
        cin>>arrayOfIntegers[k];
    }

    for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
        cout << arrayOfIntegers[k] << endl;

    cout << "The numbers of zeros in the array are: ";
    cout << countZeros(arrayOfIntegers, i);
    cout << endl;

}


int countZeros(int n[], int number)
{
    if (number > 0){ // HERE must have `number > 0` not `number >1 `
        if (n[number - 1] == 0){
            return 1 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
        }
        else{
            return 0 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
        }
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this program.

First, you don't check if your count is greater than zero.  If the user enters a count of "0" or "-2", your program will crash.

Second, the line

```
cin>>arrayOfIntegers[i];
```

that you use to read in your array does not work.  You need to use a loop; something like

```
for (unsigned j=0; j<i; ++j)
    std::cin >> arrayOfIntegers[j];
```

Third, the base case of your recursive counting function is not correct.  You need to handle the case where the first element in the array is a zero:

```
if (number > 0){ // <-- Note the change here.
    if (n[number - 1] == 0){
        return 1 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
    }
    else{
        return 0 + countZeros(n, number - 1);
    }
}
else{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not use Variable Length Arrays (VLA) in C++. So initially your program is invalid. Also you have at least to enter elements of the array in a loop.

The valid program can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>

size_t countZeros( const int[], size_t );

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    int a[N];

    std::cout << "Please input number of elements (no more than " << N << "): ";
    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << "Please input " << n << " elements: ";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cin >> a[i];

    std::cout << "The numbers of zeros in the array are: ";
    std::cout << countZeros( a, n );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


size_t countZeros( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    return ( n == 0 ? 0 : ( a[n - 1] == 0 ) + countZeros( a, n - 1 ) );
}
```

It would be better to use `std::vector` instead of the array because the size of an array is fixed and you have to specify the maximum size of the array.

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::count` declared in header `<algorithm>` in C++ that you could use instead of your recusive function. For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::cout << std::count( a, a + n, 0 );
```

Comment: thank you so much! tried it once, also tried simulating what the code does. great help indeed! hoping to learn more C++ stuff from you guys. thank you so much!